# Add/Remove or Show/Hide tab bar items from UITabbarController when using storyboards

Tags: ios, xcode, uitabbarcontroller

I have an application that needs to show different content from a `UITabBarController` based on if the user is registered or not. Is there a way to add and remove `ViewController`s from a `UITabBarController` at run-time? Show and Hide would be fine too.

Prior to storyboards you could call `setViewController` but that does not seem to be the right way when using stoaryboards.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can remove a tabbar item as follows:

```
NSMutableArray *tabbarViewControllers = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray: [self.tabBarController viewControllers]];
[tabbarViewControllers removeObjectAtIndex: /*Any index*/];
[self.tabBarController setViewControllers: tabbarViewControllers ];
```

Comment: If tabbarViewControllers array have 0 object then try it.
NSMutableArray *tabbarViewControllers = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray: [self.viewControllers]];

Answer (score 4):

**Swift 4+**

```
func removeTab(at index: Int) {
        guard var viewControllers = self.tabBarController?.viewControllers else { return }
        viewControllers.remove(at: index)
        self.tabBarController?.viewControllers = viewControllers
    }
```

Comment: Will this reload the other view controllers... I would want to keep the state of other VCs intact

Answer (score -5):

While designing in storyboard we can hide the tab bar using the option **Bottom-bar as none** in file-inspector.

[image]

Comment: This hides the entire bottom bar, not items as requested