# TabBar at the bottom of the screen which is not invoked through any item in the tab?

Tags: ios, tabs, tabbar

I am developing an application in which few of the screens open up through the tabs in the Tab Bar but some of the screens don't open from there. They open up from Hamburger View.

Could anybody please help me understand if its possible to show the Tab Bar at the bottom of the screens that don't open from there? My requirement is to show the tabs at the bottom of all the screens whether or not they open from the Tab Bar. Is this possible?

Regards,
Kavita

Answer (score 0):

If the tab bar is hidden, then use this:

self.tabBarController.tabBar.hidden = NO;

Answer (score 0):

Even if screens are not opened from any item in your hamburger view, instead of pushing or presenting that screen, you can just programmatically switch tab, hence tab bar will remain always.

For eg: you have 3 tabs showing screen1, screen2, screen3.

Now if you want to open screen3 by clicking on a menu in hamburger view, just set tabbarcontroller.selectedIndex = 2

Comment: Thanks for your response Annie. This is what I am doing for the screens that open from Tab Bar and Hamburger view both. But I'm talking about the screens that do not open from tab bar bust just Hamburger View e.g. as you said if we have screen1, screen2 and screen3 in tab bar and I need to open screen4 from hamburger (which is not there in tab bar) and still want the tab bar to be shown. Is it possible?

Comment: Oh,okay Kavita.Sorry for not understanding your question completely. Did you find a method for that? I guess you need to push screen4 from any of other screens(1,2,3) in tabbarcontroller , else you will have to programmatically change tab bar items as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13403247/add-remove-or-show-hide-tab-bar-items-from-uitabbarcontroller-when-using-storybo/13407417, then you can show screen4 using changing tab items